# NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT and return value

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging

I'm new with Swift and I begin exploring some feature for bridging with Objective-C.

Currently I have a method with `NSError` reference which is:

```
- (BOOL) verifyPersonalizationWithError:(NSError **) error NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
```

Now I can access the method in Swift for some refinements, but the return value is lost.
The generated method for Swift is:

```
open func __verifyPersonalization() throws
```

The error is correctly handled with the do catch but the return value seems to be lost.

Any missing thing for my NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT macro?

Answer (score 19):

This is unrelated to the `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` macro. The Objective-C
method

```
 - (BOOL) verifyPersonalizationWithError:(NSError **) error;
```

is imported to Swift as

```
open func verifyPersonalization() throws
```

and the only effect of the `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` macro is to prepend
underscores to the Swift method name

```
open func __verifyPersonalization() throws
```

which allows to provide a refined Swift interface in an extension, while keeping the original implementation available to be called from the refined interface
(see "Refining Objective-C Declarations" in [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)).

The Swift importer assumes that the boolean return value of the Objective-C method indicates success or
failure, which is the common Cocoa pattern 
as documented in [Using and Creating Error Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html):

> **Important:** Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the method.
>   Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in the Cocoa error 
>   domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the method indicates failure
>   by directly returning nil or NO, you should always check that the return
>   value is nil or NO before attempting to do anything with the NSError object.

A typical usage in Objective-C is

```
NSError *error;
if ([self verifyPersonalizationWithError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} else {
    NSLog(@"failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

The Swift method throws an error on failure, so there is no need
for a boolean return value:

```
do {
    try verifyPersonalization()
    print("success")
} catch {
    print("failed:", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

---

If the Objective-C method *really* indicates failure by leaving
a non-null error in the error parameter (instead of returning `false`, which is the usual Cocoa pattern) then you can indicate that
by adding a attribute:

```
- (BOOL) verifyPersonalizationWithError:(NSError **) error
    __attribute__((swift_error(nonnull_error)));
```

which is imported to Swift as

```
open func verifyPersonalization() throws -> Bool
```

The `swift_error` attribute is documented at https://github.com/apple/swift-clang/blob/383859a9c4b964af3d127b5cc8abd0a8f11dd164/include/clang/Basic/AttrDocs.td#L1800-L1819