# Throwing method cannot be an implementation of an @objc requirement because it returns a value of type `Bool`

Tags: swift, objective-c, error-handling, objective-c-protocol

I have `IKabaSDK.h` which is a (Objective-C) protocol :

```objc
@import Foundation;
@import MobileSdk;
    
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
    
@protocol IKabaSDK <NSObject>
     
- (BOOL)isStarted:(NSError* _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable)error
__attribute__((swift_error(nonnull_error)))
NS_SWIFT_NAME(isStarted());
```

I have a (Swift) class `KabaSDKThunk` where the said protocol is implemented:

```swift
class KabaSDKThunk: NSObject, IKabaSDK {
    func isStarted() throws -> Bool {
        do {
            try sdk.isStarted()
            print("thunk getIsStarted")
        } catch {
            print("thunk getIsStarted throws \(error)")
            throw error
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Xcode gives me these two errors next to my implementation:

> - Non-`@objc` method `isStarted()` does not satisfy requirement of `@objc` protocol `IKabaSDK`
> - Throwing method cannot be an implementation of an @objc requirement because it returns a value of type `Bool`; return `Void` or a type that bridges to an Objective-C class

And If I don't add `Bool` it complains that `KabaSDKThunk` does not conform to protocol `IKabaSDK` and suggests to add the `Bool` return type, so the errors are mutually exclusive. How do I solve the issue and why do we need `Bool` and `throw` here?

Comment: Read through the full question and full answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565960/ns-refined-for-swift-and-return-value for a good explanation.

Comment: @HangarRash if you feel like another question/answer has already covered the situation OP describes, flag it as duplicate with the reference to the said question/answer

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I chose not to flag it as a duplicate because the one I linked is more the opposite of what is being asked even though the answer is broad enough to cover both cases. Curious why you suggest that I flag it as a duplicate yet you chose to post an answer instead of flagging as a duplicate.

Comment: @HangarRash I personally don't think the question is a duplicate AND we are not supposed to think the same. My point was to give advise, that leaving a comment to a possible duplicate leaves the question in an undetermined state, while flagging as duplicate can potentially help to come to final conclusion and has better value for the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do we need `Bool` and `throw`

This question boils down to what you in fact want to achieve. I agree the given behaviour is inconsistent, and moreover, the Swift bridging rules were changed in the past and is likely a subject to change in future, so what you have currently broken, can turn into working sample in foreseeable future. However for now, this error says it all:

> Throwing method cannot be an implementation of an @objc requirement because it returns a value of type `Bool`; return `Void` or a type that bridges to an Objective-C class

In other words, if your Swift method is marked with `throws` keyword (and exposed to Objective-C runtime), it has to return a plain Objective-C type (not magically bridged Swift structures, like `Int`, `Bool`, `Double`, etc.. it has to be something subclassed from `NSObject`, `NSProxy` or other Objective-C entities) OR return nothing. Period. Take it as a rule (at least for now). (**P.S.** This specific situation indeed looks like an LLVM bug, because the same set of requirements works perfectly fine when applied to a non-protocol Objective-C method (submitted it [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/60024), so the community has a chance to review it))

Having that said, the proper workaround to this situation depends on your final goal.

### "Conventional" failable method

By "conventional" here I mean a contract that Cocoa/Cocoa touch programmer would usually expect. In this scenario a method with the following signature:

```objc
- (BOOL)failableMethodWithError:(NSError **)error;
```

Is commonly meant to fail wherever it returns `NO` value (in the world of Objective-C). It's uncommon for Swift to deal with indirect parameters like `NSError **` so in order to keep it consistent such methods are bridged as follows:

```swift
func failableMethod() throws
```

You can read more about this convention in the [About Imported Cocoa Error Parameters documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/about-imported-cocoa-error-parameters).

### Failable method with preserved return type with `swift_error(nonnull_error)` attribute

If you want to preserve return type AND the failable signature, you have two options. First is by giving the method `swift_error(nonnull_error)` attribute. However in this case, in order to comply with existing bridging rules, your method has to have a type that "bridges" to an Objective-C class, e.g. `NSNumber *`:

```objc
- (NSNumber *)failableMethodWithError:(NSError ** _Nullable)error __attribute__((swift_error(nonnull_error)));
```

And here is how you implement such a method in Swift:

```swift
func failableMethod() throws -> NSNumber {
    return NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false)
}
```

### Failable method with preserved return type with `swift_error(none)` attribute

Another option to preserve the return type is by disabling Objective-C - Swift error signature conversion at all with use of `swift_error(none)` attribute:

```objc
- (BOOL)failableMethodWithError:(NSError ** _Nullable)error __attribute__((swift_error(none)));
```

In this scenario you can return a scalar type from the failable method, but at the same time you will have to deal with [`NSErrorPointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserrorpointer) type:

```swift
func failableMethodWithError(_ error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {
    if (/*error condition */) {
        error?.pointee = NSError(domain: TDWErrorDomain, code: TDWErrorDomainErrorCode)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Wow detailed explanation. Thank you!